# i am not able to install bluefish or any other web editor in centOS 7 for using php

Tags: download, centos, installation, dreamweaver

to choose the best free licenced php editor for centOS 7 is confusing
dreamweaver is very good but i am unable to install it

Answer (score 0):

How abot sublime text 3 ?

```
$ wget http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/sublime_text_3_build_3065_x32.tar.bz2
```

and

```
$ sudo tar -vxjf sublime_text_3_build_3065_x32.tar.bz2 -C /opt
```